# UtmStack: Admin user and password are not working

Tags: utm

Installation went well, no issues. Rebooted machine, was able to navigate to admin login webpage at IP address. Then admin/admin user and password mentioned in documentation fail. What are the correct credentials? Is there a way to reset admin password from command line? Thank you.

[Authentication error, check your data and try again (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GlsN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an error in the documentation as the password you need to use to log in as "admin" is the same password you provided during installation.

In addition, in the new versions the password is auto-generated and is displayed at the end of the installation.